# On submit post last value fetched through while loop

Tags: php, html, forms, email

Whenever I click submit the last value of email fetched is always posted. 
what should I do to post the current email, and how to post the current email value with the selected status from each table row

```
<form action="" method="post">
<table>
<tbody>
<?php
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
echo '
<tr>
<td style="text-align:center;">
<select name="statuss">
<option selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Select Status</option>
<option value="1">Submitted</option>
<option value="2">Accepted</option>
<option value="3">Questionnaire</option>
<option value="4">Interview</option>
</select>
<input type="text" name="email" value="'.$row['email'].'">
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>

</form>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$email=(isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '');
$statuss=(isset($_POST['statuss']) ? $_POST['statuss'] : '');
$sql="update status SET personal_stylist = '$statuss' where email='$email'";
$query=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: can u please add ur select query ?

Comment: if that's your real code, you're injecting pure HTML into PHP and a missing closing brace. Edit: Besides what @David mentioned.

Comment: Your HTML is malformed.  You have one `<form>` and *many* `</form>`s.  Put the originating `<form>` inside the loop as well, and put the whole form in the table cell.  (Putting form tags between table structure tags is also invalid.)  Basically, *always* at least run your HTML through a validator to identify structural problems when you encounter something like this.

Comment: Also, of course, you're wide open to SQL injection.  Read up on prepared statements and query parameters.  There are many examples available, and it's really not difficult at all.

Comment: ...which what David means is that and in technical terms,  `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`.

Comment: How does that code even work, your while loop is not in a `<?php` block so how can it run

Comment: That edit will also generate a compile error. Please post the real code, if you post rubbish then we can only answer with what appears to be rubbish

Comment: `disabled="disbaled"` there's a spelling mistake here => `disbaled` which should read as `disabled` otherwise, that will fail you. Edit: So now you're editing "on the fly".

Comment: now please check it @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among a number of other problems with the code (which you drastically change with every edit, so it's hard to keep up), logically the `form` has no way of knowing which values you intuitively intended to post.

Simplified, you have this structure:

```
<form>
  <table>
    <row>a bunch of fields</row>
    <row>a bunch of fields</row>
    <row>a bunch of fields</row>
  </table>
</form>
```

However, each `row` has *the same fields*.  So when the form posts, it can't know which fields you were *looking at* when you submitted the form.  All it can do is package them all up into one form POST.  And as it does so, each time it encounters a field by the same name, the new field will overwrite the previous field.

Move your `<form>` to inside the rows.  Simplified again, the structure would be more like this:

```
<table>
  <row>
    <form>a bunch of fields</form>
  </row>
  <row>
    <form>a bunch of fields</form>
  </row>
  <row>
    <form>a bunch of fields</form>
  </row>
</table>
```

More specifically, make the `<form>` a descendant of the `<td>`:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  echo '
  <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
      <form>
        your form
      </form>
    </td>
  </tr>';
}
```

Comment: I was getting there but you beat me to it.

Comment: *"which you drastically change with every edit"* - Yeah, got that right David, *sigh*. Hard to say what's their "real" code, or is having everyone fix it "on the fly" as they're doing.

Comment: thanks a lot..!! that worked